# Big Shot IT company interview puzzle

Tags: performance, algorithm

This past week I attended a couple of interviews at a few big IT companies. one question that left me bit puzzled. below is an exact description of the problem.(from one of the interview questions website)

Given the data set,

```
A,B,A,C,A,B,A,D,A,B,A,C,A,B,A,E,A,B,A,C,A,B,A,D,A,B,A,C,A,B,A,F
```

which can be reduced to

```
(A; 16); (B; 8); (C; 4); (D; 2); (E; 1); (F; 1):
```

using the (value, frequency) format.

for a total of m of these tuples, stored in no specific order. Devise an O(m) algorithm that returns the kth order statistic of the data set. m is the number of tuples as opposed to n which is total number of elements in the data set.

Comment: you say "link the numerical values into a separate data structure". you are not given the numerical values, the point is to be able to generate them. also, saying "give it to a standard algo" is probably too vague.

Comment: "I [..] replied '*mumble {some bs} mumble*'" is about how this question reads.

Comment: A "standard" algorithm isn't going to look at the separate data structure.

Comment: It's hard to say without having the context of some of the other questions in the interview, but maybe they were looking for a lower level answer? Maybe they were looking for how you'd implement the ith order statistic function itself? For example, if you used your hypothetical third-party-linear-time one, how would you go back and get the character that corresponds to the result? With your example set of tuples, if you gave the frequencies as an array to the hypothetical function, requesting the 1st order statistic, it would give you `1`. But how would you go back and turn that into `d`?

Comment: I can't edit my comment to match your question anymore, but replace the `d` at the end of it with `e` or `f` and it should still make sense. Actually no it won't, because most of what I was referring to has now been edited out of your question. Ha ha, oh well.

Comment: @AdamGoodwin : i see what you mean. maybe the approach suggested by me doesnt work at all. Could you think of some other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Quick-Select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) to solve this problem.

Naively:

1. Pick an element (called the pivot) from the array
2. Put things less than or equal to the pivot on the left of the array, those greater on the right.
3. If the pivot is in position k, then you're done. If it's greater than k, then repeat the algorithm on the left side of the array. If it's less than k, then repeat the algorithm on the right side of the array.

There's a couple of details:

1. You need to either pick the pivot randomly (if you're happy with expected O(m) as the cost), or use a deterministic median algorithm.
2. You need to be careful to not take O(m^2) time if there's lots of values equal to the pivot. One simple way to do this is to do a second pass to split the array into 3 parts rather than 2: those less than the pivot, those equal to the pivot, and those greater than the pivot.

Comment: by array, are we talking about an array containing all the frequencies? I think Adam has a valid point here. After getting the ith smallest element, how do we go back and tell the element that the number corresponds to?

Comment: Store the elements in the array, not just their frequencies.

Comment: To find the original elements corresponding to the ith order statistic you could perform the quick-select on the whole tuples like Anonymous says, or you could simply get the ith order statistic from just the frequencies and look through the original set of tuples for any that have that frequency. That would take twice as long, but would still be O(m), so although not ideal it would mean you wouldn't have to implement quick-select yourself (although I suppose you can probably find quite easily a generalised quick-select implementation that works with tuples).

Comment: Your description is not clear. It looks like you are finding the kth element of the compressed array, but you need the kth element of the original array. If you do mean "position in the original array" when you say "If the pivot is in position k", please explain how you compute it.